# IOS Animation with ViewWillLayoutSubview

Tags: ios

I've this animation inside my `viewController` to shrink in and slide down my menu.

```
-(void)dismissMenuWithAnimation
{
    CGRect originalFrame = self.view.frame;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.frame = CGRectMake(originalFrame.origin.x,originalFrame.origin.y+originalFrame.size.height,originalFrame.size.width,10);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                         self.view.frame = originalFrame;
                     }];
}
```

Inside the same `viewController`, I'm overriding `viewWillLayoutSubviews`:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    CGRect viewBounds = self.view.bounds;
    self.subView1.frame = CGRectMake(self.menuItemMidPosition,viewBounds.size.height-SUBVIEW1_HEIGHT,SUBVIEW1_WIDTH,SUBVIEW1_HEIGHT);

}
```

I've a few subviews whose frame is set in this `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method. Not setting it in viewDidLoad because the frame is still incorrect then.

The problem is that when I dismiss the menu, the animations block is called first and somehow the self.view.frame is immediately set to height 10. (the reduced frame). When it reaches viewWillLayoutSubviews, the bounds height is 10. This causes my other subviews to display incorrectly.

This seems quite silly but I am not sure how to solve this. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say “This causes my other subviews to display incorrectly”?  What is incorrect about them?

Comment: Also, it appears that your view controller's top-level view (`self.view`) is the menu.  Is that correct?  Are the subviews inside the menu view?

Comment: Basically I need to get the view frame in viewWillLayoutSubview but the animation is messing up the frame by setting the frame to the frame that is at the end of the animation straight away. But to answer your question, self.view is the menu and there are subviews inside the menu view.

Answer (score 4):

I just run into the same problem as the author. Although the question is old, I will post my solution in hope that someone will bump into this question as I did.

The **solution** is very simple and totally similar to Auto Layout based animations:

```
UIView.animate(
  withDuration: 0.2,
  delay: 0,
  options: .curveEaseInOut,
  animations: {
    // This will launch viewWillLayoutSubviews!
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
},
  completion: nil)
```

And Objective-C version:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                    delay:0
                  options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
               animations:^{
                 // This will launch viewWillLayoutSubviews!
                 [self.view setNeedsLayout];
                 [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
               }
               completion:nil];
```

I like fully programmatic layout even though we have Auto Layout engine in 2017.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution is to not to use viewWillLayoutSubviews at all. I just use autoresizing masks to make sure the the frame resizes correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I found that it also works in the view a little bit later in its life cycle (it works when viewWillLayoutSubviews is invoked, but not as early as when viewWillAppear is invoked).